# After kernel upgrade, audio stops working when I plug in my Dell universal Dock D6000

Tags: sound, 20.04, dell, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 7390 laptop with Ubuntu pre-installed, and I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. AT the time I bought my laptop, I bought a Dell Universal Dock D6000. I had to install the latest DisplayLink software before it would work, and I have the latest DisplayLink version.

This morning, I upgraded to Linux 5.4.0-53-generic, and the audio on my laptops stopped working. When I unplug it from the dock, it works, and when I plug it back in, it doesn't work. I am using Wayland, which my Dell monitor recommends.

In the Sound control panel, the Output Device keeps defaulting to "Speakers - Dell Universal Dock D6000" even though I have no speakers connected to the dock. When I manually switch to "Speakers - Built-in Audio", I still get no sound, until I unplug the dock, at which time the sound comes back.

I'm stumped. I need the dock for my microphone and monitor, so I would very much like to get the sound working again.

Comment: Using the command line, speaker-test emits sound from the built-in speakers, even when the dock is plugged in. But before and afterwards, testing the output device from the control panel makes no sound if the dock is plugged in to the Thunderbolt 3 port, but does make sound if the dock is not plugged in.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this issue by rebuilding the pulse directory.

I ran the command:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse
```

and then rebooted, and the sound was restored when pulse was rebuilt.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with an XPS 13 9370 running Ubuntu 20.04 and a WD19TB dock. Rebuilding the pulse directory seems to work (and I only have to reboot once), but I'm sort of at a loss as to why.

Comment: I had this same issue with my Lenovo ThinkPad T14 and Lenovo USB-C dock. I didn't perform a kernel upgrade. I just unplugged the dock to use the laptop by itself, then plugged it back in. Audio stopped working when the dock was connected and started working when the dock was disconnected.

Your solution worked like a charm!